# Minimal reproducible example of a django project using appengine task queue (dev_appserver.py)

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, dev-appserver

I am trying to create a django project which uses AppEngine's task queue, and would like to test it locally before deploying (using gcloud`s` dev_appserver.py`).

I can't seem to find resources that help in local development, and the closest thing was a Medium article that helps setting up django with Datastore (https://medium.com/@bcrodrigues/quick-start-django-datastore-app-engine-standard-3-7-dev-appserver-py-way-56a0f90c53a3).

Does anyone have an example that I could look into for understanding how to start my implementation?

Comment: Put together a blog post - https://nocommandline.com/blog/run-a-google-app-engine-app-which-uses-django-cloud-tasks-locally/. It has sample for both the Bundled API and the Cloud Library

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can test it locally.  I'd create a new app engine project and test it there.  You should be able to stay within the free quota.

Once you have it working, you can write unit tests with mocks of task queue API calls.